# Is there a Lebesgue non-measurable Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: measure-theory

It's easy to show that every Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has inner Lebesgue measure zero. But does there exist a Lebesgue non-measurable Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes (assuming the axiom of choice, of course). The key point is that there are continuum-many $G_\delta$ null sets, and every null set is contained in a $G_\delta$-null set. This lets us perform a diagonalization construction as follows: we let $H_0=\emptyset$, and at successor stage $\eta+1<2^{\aleph_0}$ having already built $H_\eta$ we pick some real number $r$ not in the span of $H_\eta$ *and* not in the $\eta$th null $G_\delta$ set and set $H_{\eta+1}=H_\eta\cup\{r\}$. (At limit stages we take unions as usual.)

The end result $H=\bigcup_{\eta<2^{\aleph_0}}H_\eta$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-independent set which is not null (since it's not contained in any null $G_\delta$ set); extending $H$ to a Hamel basis if necessary we get a non-null (and hence non-measurable) Hamel basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!

Comment: Can't you just construct a $\mathbb Q$-independent set which meets every uncountable closed set and therefore has full outer measure?

Comment: @bof Yes, you could do that too, and that gets a strictly better result.